# unzipping self-extracting 7-zip exe files in java

Tags: java, exe, unzip, 7zip, self-extracting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I read from a Winzip self-extracting (exe) zip file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924895/how-can-i-read-from-a-winzip-self-extracting-exe-zip-file-in-java)

I need to unzip self-extracting 7-zip exe files in java.

I tried looking through many posts which did not help me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can't you just run them using Runtime exec?

Comment: You're assuming that a) the .exe is not malicious, b) he's running on a windows platform. Perhaps both are true... just sayin'

Comment: 7zip [provides SDKs](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) for C, C++, C# and Java and there is also a [3rd party port](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/) of 7zip for Java.

Comment: Thanks eugene. I am checking the sdk but it seems like there is no example for it. Is there any way to provide an example?