# zip file corrupted or has NUL bytes at the beginning correct it and re create the zip in Java

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, zipoutputstream, zipinputstream, zipstream

we are receiving a zip file through http post url,some times this zip file is corrupted or while zipping from source contains NUL bytes while it is adding the files to the zip when ever it takes more time to create the files to zip. Now we have followed the approach specified in the below link, instead of extracting into a directory we need to re-zip the corrected zip entries back into zip file and place the zip initially in one folder like input folder and after verifying/processing the zip entries we need to move the corrected zip to another folder like archive. Please help on this.

Actually looking for how to create zip from zip input stream or from scanner after the NUL bytes are skipped from it.

[Unzip error in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788373/unzip-error-in-java)

Thanks.